# Fancybox 2 in iframe of facebook page with a page load

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, iframe, fancybox-2

I'm trying to make an application in a facebook page with the use of fancybox 2 where a page is loaded as an iframe in the fancybox. It works all fine, except in IE (who would've known!).

In my fancybox 2 there is a button that submits a form and sends you to another page. this page is loaded in the same fancybox window as the previous page. When this page is loaded, the height of the fancybox is not adjusted properly, so half of my page is not visible.

What I'm trying to do now is change the height of the fancybox iframe, but I'm already stuck on getting the actual size of the iframe.

here my javascript code in the last page that is loaded in the fancybox iframe:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inner = $('.fancybox-inner');
    console.log(inner);
});
```

This console.log gives me 'null' back, which tells me this class does not exist in the page.
I have also tried the following:

```
parent.$('.fancybox-inner');
parent.$('.fancybox-iframe');
$('.fancybox-iframe');
$.fancybox;
parent.fancybox;
```

my fancybox load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".uploadbox").fancybox({
    scrolling : 'no',
    preload   : true,
    type      : 'iframe',
    width     : '623px',
    height    : 'auto',
    autoSize  : true,
    afterLoad : function () { $.fancybox.update(); }, //this does not work
    closeBtn  : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        helpers     : { 
            overlay : {closeClick: false}
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never managed to solve this issue. I'll explain to you why:

Facebook pages use an iframe to show your website into their website. To show another page into fancybox 2 you need to use an iframe too. Because an iframe in an iframe is always giving problems (cross browser and so on), there was no way to give the parent window the height of my fancybox, because of the double iframe. Since the app had to go live, I decided to give it a static height. In the future I will not use Fancybox 2 anymore or any of that matter, it's just one big misery inside Facebook.

Answer (score -1):

You will need parent.jQuery.fancybox.resize(); or even window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.resize();

If i remember correctly, there was a specification on their site about this very issue.

Comment: if I do this in the console of any browser,it gives me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fancybox' of undefined". Which is basically my problem

Comment: When you open an iframe in fancybox, be sure to open the console for the iframe not form the parent page. Then, from that console try: window.parent.jQuery - that should give you the jquery object, next, try window.parent.jQuery.fancybox should give you the fancybox object.

Comment: .resize(); is an option from the first version of fancybox, thus not work. .update(); is the way to go in v2, altho that is not working either :(

Comment: this is what window.parent.jQuery.fancybox returns : 'function (){b.open.apply(this,arguments)}'. I don't think this is what it's supposed to be.

Comment: It's exactly what it needs to be :) use your iframed content width/height to call parent window fancybox which in turn will modify  it's width/height manually (set width/height on fancy-outer, or whatever the name is)

Comment: I managed to change the height of the fancybox in the console of my browser. But if I put this piece of code in my project, it isn't working. It's not giving me an error tho. (it's set in the $(document).ready