# fancybox in iframe open from the parent in facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, fancybox

I am working on an iframe app in facebook. in my app there is a popup box(fancybox). is it possible to open the fancybox according to the main window? right now its opening in the iframe. because the codes are in the iframe. i want it to open like from the parent facebook page. is it possible?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    });
});
</script>
<a id="inline" href="#videoData'.$k.'" title=""><img  src="'.$v[thumbnail_link].'" class="mfbvideothumbs" /></a>
```

Comment: No, because it's a cross domain issue. Read about "Same origin policy".

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/15980467/1055987